# D2007 ClientDataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I would like to know whether it is feasible to use a ClientDataset with data-aware controls, when adding or editing an Interbase record.

My intention is to open just a single record initially, using a SQLDataset, but I was hopeful that I could load that record into a Clientdataset, then clone the dataset when it came time to append or edit a record. The logic being that the data-aware controls would be aware of the record state, thereby simplifying the add\edit process.

If there is a resource, or advice, that might help, I would be most grateful.

Regards & TIA

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a ClientDataset with all data aware controls.

They can be seen as light weight databases and to transfer data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. 
That said I nearly always use non data aware components in combinations with a clientDataSet and a Dataprovider. This way I have full manual controle over the data when i have tu write them back to the disconenected database.
I like this way of working specialy when I have complex SQL with a lot of joins etc.